# поменять столбцы и строки в матрице местами. Не могу найти ошибку, на первых строках выводятся нули. Должно получится из 147 258 369-> 741 852 963

Tags: pascal

```
program vv;
var a:array[1..3,1..3] of integer;
k,i,j,c:integer;
begin
  k:=0;
  for j:=1 to 3 do begin
      for i:=1 to 3 do begin
        k:=k+1;
        a[j,i]:=k;
        write(a[i,j],' ');
        end;
        writeln;
      end;
    for j:=1 to 3 do begin
      c:=A[1,j];
    A[1,j]:=A[3,j];
      A[3,j]:=c
    end;
    writeln;
    for i:=1 to 3 do begin
      for j:=1 to 3 do begin
        write(a[j,i],' ');
      end;
   writeln;
   end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет внимательнее смотреть на то, что вы пишете.
`a[j,i]:=k; write(a[i,j],' ');` 
Вы присваивает значения к элементу с одними индексами, а выводите с другими...
`a[j,i]:=k; write(a[j,i],' ');` 
Присваиваете j i, а выводите i j
В остальном, в коде проблем не нашел